# Limitar número de caracteres de casas decimais javascript

Tags: javascript, html

O utilizador pode inserir valores numa input text. O que acontece, é que quero limitar o número de caracteres depois do ponto. Exemplo válido:

> 2.324
>
> 2343423.432

Ou seja, o utilizador não pode inserir mais de três casas decimais. Cada vez que é inserido um carácter, tenho que validar esta situação. Quando esta situação acontece, a input não deixa escrever mais nenhuma casa decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que podes usar algo assim:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var oldVal = '';
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var parts = this.value.split('.');
    if (parts && parts[1] && parts[1].length > 3) this.value = oldVal;
    oldVal = this.value;
});
```

A ideia é partir a string pelo `.` e saber o comprimento (*length*) da parte depois do ponto. Se fôr maior que 3, então substituir o valor pelo antigo.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9knc3zg/